# Oauth with next-auth gives unexpected (302) error

Tags: next.js, oauth, next-auth

I am trying to build a website that allows sign in using Google using nextJS. However, I keep getting the following errors after pressing the sign-in button.

This is the
[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bcSL.jpg) that I currently have

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1VAJ.png) that I keep getting

Here are the relevant code pieces

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

const Nav = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const [providers, setProviders] = useState(null);
  const [toggleDropdown, setToggleDropdown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initProviders = async () => {
      const response = await getProviders();
      setProviders(response);
    }
    initProviders();
  }, [])

  return (
    <nav className='flex-between w-full mb-16 pt-3'>
      <Link href='/' className='flex gap-2 flex-center'>
        <Image
          src='/assets/images/logo.svg'
          alt='logo'
          width={30}
          height={30}
          className='object-contain'
        />
        <p className='logo_text'>Rate My Landlord</p>
      </Link>

      {/* Desktop Navigation */}
      <div className='sm:flex hidden'>
        {session?.user ? (
          <div className='flex gap-3 md:gap-5'>
            <Link href='/create-prompt' className='black_btn'>
              Create Post
            </Link>

            <button type='button' onClick={signOut} className='outline_btn'>
              Sign Out
            </button>

            <Link href='/profile'>
              <Image
                src={session?.user.image}
                width={37}
                height={37}
                className='rounded-full'
                alt='profile'
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>      
          {providers &&
              Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  key={provider.name}
                  onClick={() => {
                    signIn(provider.id);
                  }}
                  className='black_btn'
                >
                  Sign in
                </button>
              ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>

      {/* Mobile Navigation */}
      <div className='sm:hidden flex relative'>
        {session?.user ? (
          <div className='flex'>
            <Image
              src={session?.user.image}
              width={37}
              height={37}
              className='rounded-full'
              alt='profile'
              onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(!toggleDropdown)}
            />

            {toggleDropdown && (
              <div className='dropdown'>
                <Link
                  href='/profile'
                  className='dropdown_link'
                  onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                >
                  My Profile
                </Link>
                <Link
                  href='/create-prompt'
                  className='dropdown_link'
                  onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                >
                  Create Prompt
                </Link>
                <button
                  type='button'
                  onClick={() => {
                    setToggleDropdown(false);
                    signOut();
                  }}
                  className='mt-5 w-full black_btn'
                >
                  Sign Out
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            {providers &&
              Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  key={provider.name}
                  onClick={() => {
                    signIn(provider.id);
                  }}
                  className='black_btn'
                >
                  Sign in
                </button>
              ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import { db } from '@utils/database';

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      console.log("session");
      const sessionUser = await db.user.findUnique({ where: { email: session.user.email } });
      session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();
      
      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ account, profile, user, credentials }) {
      console.log("sign in");
      try {
        console.log(profile);
        const result = await db.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: profile.email
          }
        });
        console.log(result);
        if (!result) {
          console.log("the user is no found in the database");
          await db.user.create({
            data: {
              email: profile.email,
              name: profile.name,
            }
          });
        }

        return true
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error checking if user exists: ", error.message);
        return false
      }
    },
  }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

I have searched on Google for hours and I couldn't get anything helpful / relevant

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I am assuming you have been following the tutorial on the JavaScript Mastery YouTube channel for development.

If my assumption is right, a number of people have come across this issue, and you can see the problem and different solutions right here
[Github gist](https://gist.github.com/adrianhajdin/6df61c6cd5ed052dce814a765bff9032?permalink_comment_id=4635510#gistcomment-4635510)

As per the discussion, The error has something to do with the **regex validation of the username field** in user model. You may have to remove the validation and delete the "users" collection in the database to fix the error.

There are other suggestions as well. Hope this helps.